# Elastic search restore snapshot - rename indices

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to restore all the indexes from one snapshot which have a pattern abc_xxx_indexName to be restored as abc_yyy_indexName.
I tried going through official docs of ES but it only had one example to change the index name

```
 POST _snapshot/my_repository/my_snapshot_2099.05.06/_restore
  {
  "indices": "my-index,logs-my_app-default",
  "rename_pattern": "(.+)",
  "rename_replacement": "restored-$1"
  }
```

it's useful if you rename the logs-my_app-default data stream to restored-logs-my_app-default

but it is not useful in my case, anyone tried doing this with regex or script?

Comment: What are `xxx` and `yyy` ? Are these constant strings or specific per index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the way this part works is "rename_pattern" tries to match the entire index name and if it matches it replaces the index name with the replacement using java [regex rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-). So, to achieve a substring replacement you first need to write a rule that will match your index name and capture the part that changes. So, assuming that in your example `abc_xxx_indexName` the `indexName` is variable part and the rest is static your ragex will be `abc_xxx_(.*?)` so here we are matching `abc_xxx_` and capturing `indexName` so in the replacement part we can refer to the captured `indexName` as `$1`. If we combine this together we will have:

```
POST _snapshot/my_repository/my_snapshot_2099.05.06/_restore
{
  "indices": "def_xxx_index0,abc_xxx_index1,abc_xxx_index2",
  "rename_pattern": "abc_zzz_(.+)",
  "rename_replacement": "abc_yyy_$1"
}
```

This command will do restore

- `def_xxx_index0` as `def_xxx_index0` since it doesn't match the pattern
- `abc_xxx_index1` as `abc_yyy_index1`
- `abc_xxx_index2` as `abc_yyy_index2`

In the future, please try to make your examples more consistent, they are all over the place your `abc_xxx_indexName` in the text is very different from `logs-my_app-default` and it is very difficult to understand what you actually want to achieve. Do you have parts separated by `-` or `_` and how many parts you have, etc.

Comment: @Akshatmahla I am just wondering why didn't you accept this as the solution? Is something missing in the answer? I wrote this code https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/3953, so if there is something else you want to know just ask.

Comment: Hi , I was not aware of marking comment as accepted answer. It's done now. Thankyou again!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, `abc_xxx` is a static prefix. So you can try this:

```
POST _snapshot/my_repository/my_snapshot_id/_restore
{
  "indices": "my-index,logs-my_app-default",
  "rename_pattern": "abc_(.*?)_(.*?)",
  "rename_replacement": "abc_yyy_$2"
}
```